# Layout with div floating left and centered content

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this idea in my head but I have no idea how to realize it.

Basically what I want is:

A div that floats to the left and sticks to the left side of the screen (does move along when scrolling). This div will be the navigation div.

And then a content div that is centered. Besides that there has to be a footer and a header (header is fixed size) and footer is sticky to the bottom.

Any idea how to do this? I really can't figure it out.
PS. Its ok if there is "space" between the two divs.

Comment: We can not do it for you. Please show us a case study.

Comment: yeah I have a great idea... provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have done. Also in which part you're stucked and what should be the expected output. The MCVE can go in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Don't expect us to write the code for you. Show some effort :)

Comment: I did put some effort into this, hours honestly. The problem is that all of my previous code is at work and I cannot retrieve it from home. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty simple - As far as I understand what you need ;)
Take a look on the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tm8t9/

> `position:fixed;`

Is what you need to have the things "sticky"

And for the future take a look on CSS even basic tutorials. Maybe try this
http://learnlayout.com/no-layout.html

Have nice day.